# zoom animation blurred

Tags: android, image, animation, scale, zooming

```
<scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="2.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="2.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"     android:pivotY="20%p"
       android:fillEnabled="true"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:startOffset="1000"
       android:duration="3000" />
```

Had use above code to perform zoom animation.
Code work fine but image get blurred while zooming.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use a larger, higher-resolution image and scale from a smaller size (e.g. 0.5) to its full size.

Comment: i need to zoom image from original size(from scale 1) to some thing bigger size (scale 2)

Comment: Then it’s going to be blurry. There really isn’t a way around it—where would the additional detail come from?

Comment: Look at it this way: if you double the dimensions of your image, and display it at 50% animating to 100%, it’s going to look roughly the same as it would if you animated the original image from 100% to 200%. Except it won’t be blurry.